# Can we use direct SQL Connection in graph for bulk update

Tags: acumatica

We have a requirement to insert data from view to a custom table, right now we are doing this using graph objects and which is working fine, but the issue is, for 1K records also it is taking huge amount of time, so as an alternate we wrote bulk update. We wrote view because we have some complex logic in it.
we are in SaaS environment now. The question is, can we use this kind of code, because i know SaaS doesn't support stored procedures.

please suggest. Please have a look at below code.

```
 public static void BulkInsertSalesData()
        {
            string DBConnectionString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectX"].ToString();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionString))
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT field1,field2,field3 FROM viewname where companyID = 2", con);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    using (SqlConnection destinationCon = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionString))
                    {
                        using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationCon))
                        {
                            bc.DestinationTableName = "CustomTable";
                            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("field1", "field1");
                            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("field2", "field2");
                            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("field3", "field3");
                            destinationCon.Open();
                            bc.WriteToServer(rdr);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `PXDatabase` class?

Bypassing the data access layer in Acumatica would not pass certification. There are security concerns related to direct database access. PXDatabase class allows a more direct access at the expense of skipping some validations.

Example:

```
protected virtual void UpdateKey(APVendorRefNbr vrn)
{
    PXDatabase.Insert<APVendorRefNbr>(
        new PXDataFieldAssign<APVendorRefNbr.masterID>(vrn.MasterID),
        new PXDataFieldAssign<APVendorRefNbr.detailID>(vrn.DetailID),
        new PXDataFieldAssign<APVendorRefNbr.vendorID>(vrn.VendorID),
        new PXDataFieldAssign<APVendorRefNbr.vendorDocumentID>(vrn.VendorDocumentID),
        new PXDataFieldAssign<APVendorRefNbr.siblingID>(vrn.SiblingID),

        new PXDataFieldAssign<APVendorRefNbr.createdByID>(vrn.CreatedByID),
        new PXDataFieldAssign<APVendorRefNbr.createdByScreenID>(vrn.CreatedByScreenID));
}
```

Comment: Hello Hugues Beauséjour, right now we are using this only PXDatabase.Insert, but we have some scenarios where we need to insert around 50K records. 
Right now we don't worry about certification as we are doing this for our internal purpose only, can you please suggest can we proceed with bulk insert option ?

Comment: You can't publish an uncertified customization to SaaS platform which allows direct access to database. This is not allowed.

Comment: And I don't think there's a faster way to access DB than PXDatabase which isn't a direct access. The best you can do is build a processing screen and use PXDatabase with parallel processing.

Comment: Hello Hugues Beauséjour, thank you very much for the input.